# Validation Technical Profile on Social IDP login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Within a custom policy I was able to call a custom ValidationTechnicalProfile from SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email. This validation calls a custom API to validate a claim from the user object. This works fine for local accounts but I cant figure out how to perform this same validation on social IDP accounts. Namely Google.

I have tried on the SelfAsserted-Social technical profile, however this doesn't get called as there is nothing further to collect from the user so the orch step is skipped.

My SelfAsserted-Social TP

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckInactiveEmployee" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

I also tried to add a validation technical profile to the Google-OAuth technical profile but this is not allowed as I believe it needs to be a self asserted TP.